# Understanding javascript callbacks and formal parameters

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, functional-programming

Here is an example of a question that I am slightly confused about.

Function one calls function two, and passes it a callback that has a formal parameter.

My answer:

```
function one(){
function two(callback) 
{callback (param1, param2)}
}
```

*please correct, if this is wrong*

**Questions:**

**a) Which function calls the callback?**

function two calls the callback function

**b) Which function supplies the actual parameter of the callback?**

unsure

**c) Why give a callback parameters?**

unsure

**d) What are you giving up when you have an 'asynchronous' call without supplying a callback?**

unsure

**e) Can the called function in an asynchronous call ever contain synchronous calls?**

unsure

Comment: To add more confusion to your confusion, one of the questions is incorrectly elaborated: *"Which function supplies the actual parameter of the callback?"* None: one doesn't supply parameters, one supplies **arguments**.

Comment: In your example `one` is **not** calling `two`. To your questions: a) correct, b) can't be said, because it's not shown in the code, c) Because you can execute code after asynchronous function two and you can be sure it's called when two is finished and not before, d) dynamic, e) sure it can

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: Your function is totally 100% dead code. When calling `one` `two` gets defined, then destroyed as `one` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**anatomy first**

JavaScript can be confusing because there's a [variety of ways to express functions](http://2ality.com/2012/04/arrow-functions.html) – for all intents and purposes, the functions below can be considered identical

```
// named function
function myfunc (param1, param2) {
  return returnValue
}

// function literal syntax
const myfunc = function (param1, param2) {
  return returnValue
}

// arrow function with explicit return (note { ... })
const myfunc = (param1, param2) => {
  return returnValue
}

// arrow function with implicit return
const myfunc = (param1, param2) => returnValue
```

Above you can see *functions have parameters* – below, you'll see function *calls have arguments*

```
// call myfunc with 0 arguments
myfunc ()

// call myfunc with 1 argument
myfunc (arg1)

// call myfunc with 2 arguments
myfunc (arg1, arg2)
```

---

**they're just functions**

> **a)** Which function calls the <del>callback</del> function?

So wherever we see a function supplied with *arguments*, we know we're dealing with a *call* – to answer **A**, just look to see the enclosing function of the call

```
function someFunc (param1, param2) {
  // do something
  const result = param1 * 2

  // param2 called with result
  param2 (result)
}
```

Hey look, `param2 (result)` is a function *call*. We look to the enclosing function to see that `someFunc` is the one that called it

> **b)** Which function supplies the actual parameter of the <del>callback</del> function?

Well that sounds silly doesn't it? That's like asking "Who does Bobby's name belong to?" *Bobby*, of course. You probably meant to ask, which function supplies the *argument* – in which case, that answer would be `someFunc` – it supplies `result` argument

> **c)** Why give a <del>callback</del> function parameters?

This is instantly answered as soon as we stop calling functions a *"callback"* – a callback is a *function*, not the other way around. We give functions parameters so that we can affect the behaviour of the function

> **d)** What are you giving up when you have a<del>n 'asynchronous'</del> call without supplying a <del>callback</del> function?

Don't worry about asynchronous vs synchronous function calls; there's just *function calls*. Function calls happen at different times, but at some point the call will evaluate the function's body with the supplied arguments and return the result; `undefined` or otherwise

In most cases, you "give up" the ability to do anything useful with the result – look at our function again: if we don't supply `param2`, `result` just goes unused

```
function someFunc (param1, param2) {
  // do something
  const result = param1 * 2

  // param2 called with result
  param2 (result)
}
```

But of course that's not always true. To understand why, we have to first fix your question tho

> **d)** What are you giving up when you have a call without supplying an argument?

Kind of a silly question right? But it's no different for <del>callbacks</del> functions – they're just ordinary values like anything else

Below we have `someFunc` with a function parameter naïvely named `callback` – `someFunc` produces a "valid" result with or without the callback specified – so the answer for **D** is: you give up nothing, *explicitly*

```js
function someFunc (x, callback) {
  if (callback)
    return callback (x * 10)
  else
    return x * 2
}

// with the callback
someFunc (5, console.log) // 50

// without
console.log (someFunc (5)) // 10
```

> e) Can the called function in a<del>n asynchronous</del> call ever contain <del>synchronous</del> calls?

Yes, functions can call other functions. This idea of "sync" and "async" in javascript is historically a mental construct and therefore a lot of people have differing opinions on it. To add to this, newer versions of JS have an `async` keyword which will implicitly convert your function's return value to a Promise

To further illustrate this, observe `doSomething` – is it "asynchronous" or is it "synchronous" ?

```js
// "synchronous" function
const mult = (x,y) => x * y

// "synchronous" function
const double = (x) => mult (x, 2)
  
// function with "callback"
const doSomething = (x, callback) =>
  callback (x)

// is it async ?
doSomething (5, x => {
  const result = double (x)
  console.log (result) // 10
})

// or is it sync ?
console.log (doSomething (5, double)) // 10
```

---

**where to go from here**

There *is* actually a more uniform understanding of asynchrony in JavaScript now – especially with the standardization and widespread adoption of Promises. ES2017 adds new control syntax `async`/`await` too. "Callback" patterns are mostly dead – even the dominant force that was Node with it's popular "Node-style (error first) callbacks" has conceded to support Promised-based interfaces for asynchronous programs

That's not to say higher-order functions (functions with function parameters, or functions that return other functions) are without their uses – you'll see the functional programmers waving their `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` all over the place

But this idea of "callbacks" can be extremely powerful – especially when represented in ways other than we've seen above. [Continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is a style where we pass a *continuation* (another fancy name for a function) that serves as the "next" step of our program. I've written a lot on the [subject of continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20continuation). If you find this stuff interesting, keep reading. You'll learn amazing things about the call stack, principles of recursion, functors, monads, all sorts of things !

```js
const cont = x => k => k (x)

const double = x => cont (x * 2)

const triple = x => cont (x * 3)

double (2) (console.log)                            // 4
double (2) (double) (console.log)                   // 8
double (2) (double) (double) (console.log)          // 16
double (2) (double) (double) (double) (console.log) // 32
double (2) (triple) (console.log)                   // 12
```

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation. It really solves my misunderstandings